# Error de sintaxis al utilizar nuevo parrafo

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo una funcion Javascript como esta:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if('@TempData["Message"]' != "") {
            $("#myModal").modal();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Su función es abrir un modal en caso de que el TempData venga diferente a nulo.

En el backend populo ese TempData de la siguiente manera:

```
res.Error = string.Join<string>(Environment.NewLine, errores);
TempData["Message"]  = res.Error;
```

Como pueden ver, por cada errores agrego una nueva linea.

Cuando debugeo la función con Chrome

Me da el siguiente error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

JavaScript Output:

```
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            if ('Ocurrio un error al ejecutar servicio web de Bono, para el empleado90 - NOMBRE 90 AP PAT 90 AP MAT 90
Ocurrio un error al ejecutar servicio web de Bono, para el empleado2021 - NOMBRE 2021 AP PAT 2021 AP MAT 2021
Ocurrio un error al ejecutar servicio web de Bono, para el empleado1451 - NOMBRE 1451 AP PAT 1451 AP MAT 1451
Se ejecutó el envío Bonos, sin embargo ocurrieron errores. Revisar log de errores.' != '') {
       $("#myModal").modal();
     }
});
    </script>
```

Pero no encuentro el error de sintaxis

[image: ErrorImage]

Ya intente cambiando el script a:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            if ('@Html.Raw(TempData["Message"])' != '') {
       $("#myModal").modal();
     }
});
```

Pero tampoco funcionó. Si el error es solo uno funciona correctamente. Por lo que el error es al insertar una nueva linea. Alguien tiene idea de como resolver este problema?. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error efectivamente te da por los saltos de línea.

Para evitarlo puedes usar el método `JavaScriptStringEncode` de la clase `HttpUtility`:

```
if ('@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode((string)TempData["Message"])'){
  ...
```

Comment: lo intento, pero me sale: cannot convert from object to string

Comment: Tendrás que hacer una conversión explícita: `if ('@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode((string)TempData["Message"])'){`

Comment: Funcionó, muchísimas gracias